# Why does Netty/Redisson DNS Resolver add a bracket to host name?

Tags: java, netty, redisson

I'm trying to connect to Redis on AWS via [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson), and I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$SearchDomainUnknownHostException: Search domain query failed. Original hostname: 'ec2-54-234-206-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com]' failed to resolve 'ec2-54-234-206-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com].ec2.internal' after 3 queries
```

It appears that my Redis URL is having a bracket added to the of it: `'ec2-54-234-206-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com]'`

But the original URL in the `redisson.json` is `"redis://ec2-3-82-237-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com:17199"`

Why might the `]` get added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the following bug in Redisson:
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/2370

You can resolve it by upgrading Redisson now, or using the workaround described in the issue.